# If for a command to check if it succeed

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm working on my bash script to create logical volumes. I have this command which I want to put in a if to check of each of these succeed. What is the easiest way to do that?

```
 #!/bin/bash
 pvcreate /dev/md5

vgcreate vg0 /dev/md5

lvcreate -L 200MB vg0 -n test
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

pvcreate /dev/md5 && echo "pvcreate succeeded" || echo "pvcreate failed"

vgcreate vg0 /dev/md5 && echo "vgcreate succeeded" || echo "vgcreate failed"

lvcreate -L 200MB vg0 -n test && echo "lvcreate succeeded" || echo "lvcreate failed"
```

Logical AND `&&` part will be executed only if the command succeeded(true) else Logical OR `||` (false) part will be executed.

Comment: *not succeeded*? That doesn't sound good for my ears. I'd go for *failed*.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
if pvcreate /dev/md5
then
  if vgcreate vg0 /dev/md5
  then
    lvcreate -L 200MB vg0 -n test
  fi
fi
```

Not testet. But should work.

Basic if-else structure is:

```
if condition
  then
    do somethin...
fi
```

Comment: `[` and `]` are **NOT** part of the `if` syntax. `[` is a shell builtin, an alias for `test`. The reason you end it with `]` is to make it look symmetric. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 for more information. (**Hint:** You want simply `if pvcreate /dev/md5` and so on.)

Comment: `[pvcreate` --- command not found. Please edit or remove this answer, it is plain wrong.

Comment: @myuszika7h i have removed the [ ]. Was typed in a rush.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/ksh
safeRunCommand() {
typeset cmnd="$*"
typeset ret_code

echo cmnd=$cmnd
eval $cmnd
ret_code=$?
if [ $ret_code != 0 ]; then
  printf "Error : [%d] when executing command: '$cmnd'" $ret_code
  exit $ret_code
fi
}

command="ls -l | grep p"
safeRunCommand "$command"
```

Source: [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211844/get-exit-code-for-command-in-bash-ksh)

Answer (score 1):

This would be traditional:

```
#!/bin/bash
pvcreate /dev/md5 || die "pvcreate failed"
vgcreate vg0 /dev/md5 || die "vgcreate failed"
lvcreate -L 200MB vg0 -n test || die "lvcreate failed"
```

The function `die` is something you'll have to define, which prints an error message and then exits. A sample implementation might be

```
die() {
     echo $@ 1>&2   # print arguments of 'die' to standard error
     exit 1         # exit the script
}
```

When you do it like this, the script won't produce any output unless something fails, in which case it will not go any further. If you want it to keep going even if a command fails, remove the `exit` line from the implementation of `die`.

If you want to get a message for each command that succeeds, as well, you could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if pvcreate /dev/md5; then
    echo "pvcreate succeeded"
else
    echo "pvcreate failed"
fi
```

and similarly for the other two commands.

Answer (score 0):

If all the commands depend on the one before succeeding, you can use `set -e`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

pvcreate /dev/md5
vgcreate vg0 /dev/md5
lvcreate -L 200MB vg0 -n test
```

Note that the above will exit without and specific message on which command failed.